# Cant iterate through hashes that are inside an array in perl

Tags: perl

This is my data structure.

```
   my @mysqlBooleanNumeric=(
              ( 'TR'=>" OR 1=1--", 'FAL'=>" OR 1=2--"),
              ('TR'=>"/**/OR/**/1=1--", 'FAL'=>"/**/OR/**/1=2--" )     

);
```

I use it in a function.

```
sub main{
  GetPayLoad(@mysqlBooleanNumeric);
}
```

This is the function.

```
   sub GetPayLoad{

           my(@payloads,%categories,$key,$value);
           (@payloads)=@_;


for my $i (0 .. $#payloads ) {

            foreach my $key ( keys $payloads[$i] )
            {
                print "$payloads[$i]{$key}\n";
            }

      }
}
```

This is what I get..

> Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref

UPDATE:

This doesnt work too, BTW

```
 sub GetPayLoad{

           my(@payloads);
           (@payloads)=@_;

        for my $payload (@payloads){

               for my $key (sort keys %$payload){
                   print "$payload->{$key} \n";
               }

        }

}
```

> Can't use string ("TR") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in

I create my code like in this example:

[enter link description here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch09_03.htm)

But it doesn towrk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous hashes are introduced in curly brackets, not round parentheses:

```
my @mysqlBooleanNumeric = (
  { TR => ' OR 1=1--',       FAL => ' OR 1=2--'},
  { TR => '/**/OR/**/1=1--', FAL => '/**/OR/**/1=2--'},     
);
```

Using round brackets is equivalent to

```
my @mysqlBooleanNumeric = ( 'TR', ' OR 1=1--', 'FAL', ' OR 1=2--',
                            'TR', '/**/OR/**/1=1--', 'FAL', ' \/**/OR/**/1=2--');
```

Comment: That is a messy solution. I want to have array of hashes. It also thinks that I have 8 elements in the array, when I use that syntax..how come?

Comment: @user2873728: The solution is the *first* code sample. He is saying that what *you have written* is equivalent to the second code sample.